# Error running SQL statement generated in code

Tags: mysql, sql

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `new_db2`(`name`, `price`, `add_date`, `image`) " + "VALUES ('"+name+"','"+p_price+"','"+date+"','"image"')";
```

i have ';' error expected in this Sql query please help me to solve this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting anything. Put some effort.

Comment: How does the final string look? (BTW, don't name tables as _db_-something, just too confusing...)

Comment: Can you give us the exact error message - does it mean "unexpected ; in sql" or "; expected in SQL"

Comment: He obviously is not concatenating strings properly. Not sure which language this is though.

Comment: I think this is java, the variable image is not concatenate : up vote
-4
down vote
favorite
String query = "INSERT INTO `new_db2`(`name`, `price`, `add_date`, `image`) " + "VALUES ('"+name+"','"+p_price+"','"+date+"','"+image+"')";

Comment: I thoroughly recommend you spend a while reading http://bobby-tables.com/ and really getting to grips with the concept therein; first, it will solve your problem, second it will prevent you forever more writing low performance, insecure database code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the language you are using (I suppose Java) but may be you should write the statement like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO `new_db2`(`name`, `price`, `add_date`, `image`) " + "VALUES ('"+name+"','"+p_price+"','"+date+"','"+image+"')";
```

(lack of **+** before and after **image**)